# What does T statistics of Information Coefficient indicate?

Tags: time-series, information

Hi I am looking for a clear explanation of T statistics concept. Especially in quantitative equity portfolio management context, what does T statistics of monthly Information Coefficient for one factor indicate? How can I tell if it is significant, and if it is, any useful information I could derive from that?

Comment: A better place for asking this question might be [stats.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).